# EhCache CacheLoaderWriter.load() not called after cache entry expired

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I have created simple EhCache test with CacheLoaderWriter:

```
Cache<Long, BigInteger> cache = cacheManager.getCache("aCache3", Long.class, BigInteger.class);
assertEquals(cache.get(2L), BigInteger.ONE);
Thread.sleep(6000);
assertEquals(cache.get(2L), BigInteger.ONE); // fails here with null!=1
```

When the cache entry with key 2L expire after the sleep, the cache.get(2L) returns null value. In my opinion it should first call CacheLoaderWriter.load() method to fetch the right value from SoR and then return it.

Could you please explain why this happens and how I can change this behavior? Is there any additional configuration option or am I missing something?

ehcache.xml:

```
<cache alias="aCache3" uses-template="default">
    <key-type>java.lang.Long</key-type>
    <value-type>java.math.BigInteger</value-type>
    <expiry><ttl unit="seconds">4</ttl></expiry>
    <loader-writer >
        <class >com.example.jeight.ehcache.MapCacheLoaderWriter</class>
    </loader-writer>
    <resources>
        <heap unit="entries">10</heap>
        <disk persistent="false" unit="MB">10</disk>
    </resources>
```

MapCacheLoaderWriter:

```
public class MapCacheLoaderWriter implements CacheLoaderWriter<Long, BigInteger> {

    private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private Map<Long, BigInteger> map;

    public  MapCacheLoaderWriter() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long k) throws Exception { }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll(Iterable<? extends Long> ks) throws BulkCacheWritingException, Exception {    }

    @Override
    public BigInteger load(Long k) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Cache load: " + k);
        if (!map.containsKey(k)) {
            BigInteger v = fib(k);
            map.put(k, v);
        }
        return map.get(k);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<Long, BigInteger> loadAll(Iterable<? extends Long> ks) throws BulkCacheLoadingException, Exception {
        Map<Long, BigInteger> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (Long k : ks) {
            load(k);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Long k, BigInteger v) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Cache write: " + k + " " + v);
        map.put(k, v);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeAll(Iterable<? extends Entry<? extends Long, ? extends BigInteger>> kvMap)
        throws BulkCacheWritingException, Exception {
        for (Entry<? extends Long, ? extends BigInteger> k : kvMap) {
            write(k.getKey(), k.getValue());
        }
    }

    private BigInteger fib(long k) {
       // some code returning a non-null value
    }
}
```

Comment: Will try to reproduce locally - this should not behave like that according to a quick read of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that needs fixing - [filed it](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/issues/1598) in Ehcache.

Thanks for the report!

The only thing you can do to not have the issue is to limit your cache to a single tier - either heap if you can live with the smaller set of entries or disk if you can live with the added deserialization on each `get`.